# PHP mySQL jQueryJavascript page redirect failed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have an index.php page that contains a searchbox that a user can search by name,, the backendsearch.php feeds the data to this searchbox.

everything is working except for the click event from the search result..

what i want to create is that after a user clicks a name,the user will be transferred to the update.php page that contains the name and other information that corresponds to the search result.

this is what i have so far:

this is the backendsearch.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ajax_crud");

if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name LIKE ?";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);
    $param_term = $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo "<p>" . $row["name"] . "</p>";
    }
}
else{
            echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

and this is my index.php code that contains the said searchbox:
(in only included the relevant lines)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){

    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(inputVal.length){
        $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){

          resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
    } else{
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }
});
$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
$(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
$(this).parent(".result").empty();
var link = "update.php?name=$name";
 console.log(link);
window.location = link;
    });
});
</script>
```

and the searchbox:

```
<div class="search-box">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" />

<div class="result">
</div>
</div>
```

i just couldn't find the right way to write the script that will transfer the user to the update.php page that corresponds with the name result.

thanks in advance for those who can help.

Comment: `$name` is a PHP variable? If so you need to `echo` it and open it with `<?php` tags.

Comment: i tried changing this code from my backendsearch.php

    echo "<p>" . $row["name"] . "</p>";

to

echo ('<p><a href="update.php?id=%s">%s</a></p>', $row['id'], $row['name']);

but it did not work..

can anyone heLp me correct this code?

Comment: Could you please add **console.log($(this).text())** right after **console.log(link)** and post both outputs?

Comment: just tried it, unfortunately it's still the same..